# Traducir un código en C++ a Pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

¡Hola! Si me pueden ayudar a pasar este código que está en C a Dev-pascal. He estado tratando de pasar el código a Pascal, aunque he visto algunas similitudes entre los lenguajes, no logro pasarlo por completo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int matriz [12][12];
    int min=0;//valor mínimo
    int max=0;//valor máximo

    for (int fila =0; fila < 12; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12;columna++)
        {
            int valor = matriz[fila][columna]= 2 * ((rand() % 256) + 1);

            cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " ";

            if(valor<min){
                min=valor;
            }
            if(valor>max){
                max=valor;
            }
        }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<< "*************************************************" << endl;
    //debes imprimir el valor mínimo y el máximo

    system("pause");
}
```

Esto es lo que he logrado pasar a Pascal:
[image: Esto es lo que he logrado pasar a Pascal]

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Sugiero que si ya has pasado una parte la subas también así te ayudamos con lo que realmente tienes problemas. Así también la pregunta será mejor recibida.

Comment: ¡Gracias por el consejo!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques código en imágenes. Tal como hiciste con el código de C, publica el código de pascal directamente como código.

Answer (score 2):

Las partes vitales que te faltan diría que son:

1. Inicialización de la semilla de pseudo-randomización:

   - c++

```c++
     srand(time(NULL));
```

- pascal (ojo, esta llamada no es necesario hacerla explícitamente en versiones modernas de Pascal, como Delphi, dónde la RTL hace la inicialización automáticamente.

```pascal
     Randomize();
```

1. Generación de un número pseudo-aleatorio dentro de un rango

   - c++ la función rand() devuelve un número entero entre 0 y RAND_MAX. Se utiliza el *truco* del residuo para obtener un número dentro del rango deseado, utilizando el operador `%`. Así, el código mostrado devolverá siempre un número entre 0 y 255.

```c++
     rand() % 256
```

- Pascal. La función `Random()`, si se llama sin argumentos, devuelve un número de coma flotante, tal que 0 <= x < 1. Es decir, entre 0 y 0.9999999 (si se me permite la libertad de expresarlo de esa manera).

  Sin embargo, si pasamos un parámetro entero a `Random(Rango: Integer)`, nos devolverá un número entero entre `0` y `Rango - 1`, con lo que podemos sustituir directamente por el código que se encuentra más adelante. El resto del cálculo se haría exactamente igual:

```pascal
     Random(256)
```

1. Imprimir a pantalla

   - c++ el macro cout termina *imprimiendo* a la salida estándar, que suele ser la pantalla

```c++
     cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " ";
     cout <<endl;
```

- Pascal. Las funciones `Write()` y `Writeln()` realizan la misma función, la diferencia es que `Writeln()` al final *imprime* los caracteres  de fin de línea. Ambas funciones *mágicamente* soportan cualquier número de parámetros, incluyendo ser llamadas sin parámetros.

```pascal
     Write(matriz[i, j], ' ');
     Writeln;
```